# How can I search in Jira for issues in any project that starts with a word

Tags: jira

I am trying to create a dashboard widget in Jira that shows open defects across multiple projects.

I need the graph to show issues for any project that starts with a specific term (e.g. like project ~ "prototype" or project = "prototype*" etc) but those don't seem to be valid searches

It seems like Jira does not allow searches to include any logic for the field "project" other than `=`, `!=`, or `IN`

Note:  I cannot use any special plugins, as I don't have admin access.

Comment: Just to clarify what I understand, you want a filter in JIRA which shows list of all open defects across all the projects starting with a particular word. So that you can create a dashboard widget, right?

Comment: exactly.  we have like 50 projects, and I want to be able to do reporting for about 5-10 of those

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this without calling out each project with an OR or something.

You could add a label to each issue on these projects then just search by label. You can group edit a query if you want to label everything with the same label.

Comment: yes, I can certainly hard code the project names, but that is going to be painful to maintain, as the query will need to be edited each time a new project is added, but it could work

Comment: Yes, for 5-10 projects I would use either the OR project name approach or labels.  You have to remember to add the label but it should have meaning and without it, stop it showing elsewhere so soon you will know to make sure when you add a new project you add the label.  Hopefully not more than 2-5 projects per week.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be the usage of Project Categories.

They can be found / created under Administration -> Projects -> Project categories.

When You defined a category (e.g. Prototype) You can associate the category with the project on the Project Admin Page.

Now You can search via JQL: `category = Prototype`

Comment: I have asked for admin rights to make project categories but don't have that yet.  this might be the easiest solution, if I can get that

Answer (score 0):

Some fields will let you use CONTAINS:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-764478330.html
Summary, Description, Environment, Comments, custom fields that use the "Free Text Searcher" (i.e. custom fields of the following built-in custom field types: Free Text Field, Text Field, Read-only Text Field).

For example you can do

```
description ~ 'QUOT'  order by created DESC
```

but not

```
project ~ 'QUOT'  order by created DESC
```